# What kind of adapter do I need to connect this external monitor?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have a MacBook Pro 2017.  I would like to connect an external monitor, [an Asus MZ27AQ Designo 27” Monitor WQHD IPS DP HDMI Eye Care Monitor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076DMGZLR), but I'm unclear how or if this is possible.  What kind of adapter would I need to connect this type of monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you register your Mac with iCloud / AppleID and then use the iOS Apple Store app - it shows compatible adapters. Two I know that work well are the Apple USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter adapter and another is the Belkin USB-C to HDMI Adapter

- https://store.apple.com/xc/product/MUF82AM/A
- https://store.apple.com/xc/product/HKQ22ZM/A

[Monoprice also has great value and quality adapters](https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=21880) in general, but I’ve not tested these specific ones yet.

[image: Apple USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter]

Comment: The MBP supports DisplayPort.  There's no need to mess around with adapters, and expecially no need to take a perfectly good DP output and turn it into HDMI.

Comment: @MarcWilson great answer you provided. I’ve had higher failure rate with DP to USB-C but maybe we just had bad luck with our purchasing at work.

Answer (score 1):

Your MBP supports DisplayPort.  The monitor supports DisplayPort.  Put a cable between them, you're done.  No need to mess around with adapters.

Something like this from Amazon: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01J6DT070](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01J6DT070)

Comment: Good call, you don’t need HDMI. We’ve had those type cable fail at work far more often than HDMI but the idea is sound. +1 since we got six months out of these before they starting failing us. For a one off, save the money on HDMI is a safe bet.